# General questions + How: object that can copy another object's values?

Tags: java, class, object, methods

General part first:

This is for my Java 1 final: I need to make an NFL playoff simulator. So, I would make a "Team" object that holds values for "Offense" and whatnot.  I would need a method that holds an algorithm to calculate who wins each matchup.  However, I don't know how to go about applying the method to the appropriate teams..

I was going to make another object called "Matchup" which would hold 2 "Team" objects, then comparing the 2 teams' values with the algorithm method.  But, I don't think you can use objects inside another object, to my knowledge... Therefore, I've just been trying to hard-code everything in an ugly way.

Would anyone point me in the right direction of forming such a program?

Anyway, on to my immediate issue:

Here is my small bit of code thus far..

```
public class Final_Larrabee {
    static Team pit = new Team("Steelers", "AFC", 3, 75, 70);
    static Team bal = new Team("Ravens", "AFC", 6, 70, 80);
    static String teamA1 = "bal";

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        System.out.println(+teamA1.seed);
    }
}
```

And my other class:

```
package final_larrabee;

public class Team {

    String name;
    String conference;     
    int seed;
    int offense;     
    int defense;        
    boolean wcWin;
    boolean divWin;        
    boolean conWin;        
    boolean alive;        

    public Team(String n, String c, int s, int o, int d) {    
        name = n; 
        conference = c;
        seed = s;
        offense = o;
        defense = d;
        wcWin = false; // these wins will be used in the betting part
        divWin = false;
        conWin = false;
        alive = true; // determines if team is out of playoffs or not
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String n){
        name = n;
    }

    public int getConference(){
        return this.seed;
    }

    public void setConference(String c){
        conference = c;
    }

    public int getSeed(){
        return this.seed;
    }

    public void setSeed(int s){
        seed = s;
    }

    public int getOffense(){
        return this.offense;
    }

    public void setOffense(int o){
        offense = o;
    }

    public int getDefense(){
        return this.defense;
    }

    public void setDefense(int d){
        defense = d;
    }
}
```

I realize this won't work, because it is trying to access teanA1's seed value (which doesn't exist of course).  But, what I wanted was to simply call the bal.seed value.  I wanted to do it this way so that later, I can use teamA1 and teamA2 variables for the 2 teams in a given matchup.  Is there a way to do it this way?

If not, perhaps ideally, it would be best to create a Team object called teamA1 which holds the values of whatever team I need at the time.  It would need to change like a variable instead of make a million objects every time I need it (ideally..)  I found the method 'clone' but I'm not sure this is what I want?

Any help, be it to my immediate question, or the general layout of my program, would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can put objects inside other objects. What told you you could not do that? Have you tried?

Comment: I googled it and people said you can't.  I also tried it.  But they could be wrong, and I probably did it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as your class Final_Larrabee holds 2 team objects in your code, your matchup class can also hold other objects.

Yes, you're on the right track with the idea of creating a matchup class which holds instances of team objects.

Inside your main class you can initialize 2 team objects. I would then create a matchup object, which gets passed the 2 team objects you have previously created and do some functionality.

Inside your team class you could implement a method, which returns a score based on the teams stats. For example it could calculate the offense * defence * seed or something like and return it that and then inside your match class, you can then implement a method such as playGame() which calls the getScore() method of each object and compares the values and then returns the winner (or prints them out for simplicity).

As regards your code, you're using the keyword **static**. Static is a keyword which changes a variable/object/method to a class variable/object/method. This means that every instance of the class shares this variable. I would not use it for creating the teams. An example of where to use static (a very basic example), would be if for some reason you needed to keep track of the amount of team objects you created. You could implement a static COUNT variable inside the team object and increase it by one every time the constructor is called. This could also be used for assigning IDs to the teams.

```
static int TEAM_COUNT = 0;

public Team()
{
   this.id = ++TEAM_COUNT;
}
```

This would make the TEAM_COUNT be a value which shared by all instances of the class team. If you were to call

```
teamA.setTeamCount(0);
```

Then every other instance of Team would also be reset to 0.

Edit: With regards to your playoffs

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Team team1 = new Team("parameters required here");
    Team team2 = new Team("parameters required here");   
    Playoff p = new Playoff();
    p.add(team1);
    p.add(team2);
    p.startPlayoffs();
}
```

If you create all of the objects inside the main class, then they are available to that method as they are local. When you call p.add(), you can add them to an array or collection, which is inside the Playoff class. Your startPlayoffs() method can then process the array of objects already stored inside the class.

Comment: Thank you, I will explore all your suggestions and see if I can figure it out.  But, I need to make 12 teams, and the teams that would need to be matched up would have to change depending on which teams are still alive.  For instance, I could hard-code NE to play Seattle in the super bowl, but I need it to be whichever 2 teams are left standing.  I think to do this I would need some kind of variable / if statements that would determine who is still left.  Any ideas?

Comment: You're probably better off creating a Playoff class instead of a Matchup class then. Inside your main method you could create 12 instances of the Team class and add them an object of type Playoff. You could then call playoff.startPlayoffs() and inside that method do some processing of the collection of teams. For example you could create a loop, which runs until there's only 1 team left and constantly compares teams inside the array and knocks one out of the playoff. When there is only one team left you can then print out the winning team. Ps: If this was of any help, please upvote! :)

Comment: I can't up vote because I don't have the reputation to it says, but I clicked the check mark on your answer.  Thanks again.

One last quick thing: How exactly do I get access the teams from my main to my new Matchup (or playoff) class?  Example: Team home = Final_Larrabee.pit; // is not working

Comment: I've edited my answer giving your a push in the correct direction. You will now need to build the Playoff class which stores an array, or some form of collection for the teams. Inside your startPlayoffs() method you can then process this.

Answer (score 2):

make team implements comparable this will give you the ability to write compareTo method and then you can put you win condition based